# Block enter key when less than 4 digits entered

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a code in my script that will block enter key until 4 digits entered in a text field.

Here are my forms:

```
<div id="inputtext">
      <input type="text" id="dreamtext" maxlength="45" spellcheck='false' autofocus/>
      <input type="submit" id="nextstepbutton" value="next step" onclick="window.open('step3.html','_self','resizable=yes')" />
    </div>
```

This particular script hides submit button when < 4 characters entered and shows it when 4 or more entered. It also modifies some div content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $("#nextstepbutton").hide();

     $("#dreamtext").keyup(function() {
         var val = $(this).val();
         if (val.length > 3) {
             $('#nextstepbutton').show();
             document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<h1>hit return or next step</h1>";
         }
         else {
             $('#nextstepbutton').hide();
             document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<h1>type please</h1>";
         }

     });
});
</script>
```

This script presses submit button when enter key pressed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dreamtext").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#nextstepbutton").click();
    }
});
</script>
```

Now, what is the best way to block the enter key when less than 4 digits entered? Thanks

Comment: Far better to use a submit listener that checks the value and cancels submit if it's not the required length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in the keydown(/up/press) event called preventDefault.
This makes any default action not happen.

```
$("#dreamtext").keyup(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length < 4) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#nextstepbutton").click();
    }
});
```

You could also connect it to the jQuery `.submit()` handler.

```
    $("#someForm").submit(function(){
      if ($("#dreamText").val().length < 4)  {
        return false;
      }
    })
```

Comment: Try by setting maxlength="4".

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Maybe I should modify my second script so it would press enter only if 4 or more characters entered?

Comment: Did you see the last paragraph i just added? Remember to switch `#someForm` to your form tag :)

Comment: `$("#dreamText").val()` would be much more efficient as `this.dreamText.value`.

Comment: I replaced if with else if here: else if (event.keyCode == 13) and it worked